# What is the correct verb regarding to a participating as a teacher of a course

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct regarding to doing a course? I would like to say that I'm the **teacher** of a course, but I want to use a **verb**. Now if I say "I **do** a course" it can mean that I'm the student there. Isn't it? After some searching I found that I can say "to **deliver**" course, but I found [this source](https://tlt-swg.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/if-you-deliver-course-you-dont-own-it.html) that seems to be against this usage of deliver a course. Are there other options? What about the verb **conduct**?

Comment: Why not "teaching a course"? Or "holding a class on..."?

Comment: While "Teaching a course" I can understand, "holding a class on..." is not clear to me. Is it can be understood in the same meaning that I want? what about conduct and deliver, are they indeed widely accepted for the required meaning?

Comment: Is the "course" one class or a series of classes (such as one semester "Math 101")?

Comment: *deliver* however is wrong, because you deliver a speech, the mail, etc. It indicates a more specific action than a class or course that occurs over a period of time and may have many topics and interaction.

Comment: @user3169 it is a series of classes (like one semester as you said).

Comment: Then a student *takes* a course, and the instructor *teaches* it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could say "I conduct an English course" , but if you simply said "I conduct a course" I would be confused because course can refer to something other than a class. "Course" is a word that has several meanings.

It would be easiest to say "I teach English", "I teach swimming lessons".  Teach is the verb you would use.  Teaching is using the verb 'teach' in the present tense, you are doing it now.

You could also say "I deliver a course in college". Deliver is correct, but not used very often.  Again, I would add an adjective to course so that people understand that you are using 'course' as a subject in school.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the article "deliver" is fine. He is arguing about the connotation with postal delivery (where engagement often doesn't even extend to delivery but a "Sorry we missed you. Collect at" note slipped under the door without a knock or ring). As an engineer I produce "deliverables" and responsibility after the event is implicit if not explicit. Teachers as a profession also have such an implicit responsibility, and being replaceable is something to aspire to.

Be careful with "course" as said it has several meanings but also in different countries it means different things too, e.g. one subject or a group (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_(education))) with some blurring between the two. As a term its meaning is changing, which also doesn't help anyone try to gauge the meaning of the term. From here on out I'll use course(s) to indicate course in the single subject sense and course(g) to indicate a group of subjects (subjects and classes are also not great terms but I don't want to blather on too long).

One wouldn't teach a course(g) but subjects, as course(g)s tend to overlap and have subjects (and thus the people teaching them) in common. You could say conduct a course(g); this would imply being active in the course(g) design and/or administrative or managerial side of it though. To run a course(g) is similar. To conduct or run a course(s) works fine, but does imply more breadth of meaning than teaching (design, administration, assessment) which you may very well want to express.

Also if in doubt be vague:

"I inspire a thirst for discovery in the open-minded"